# Fill regular polygons with 2 colors

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, polygon

I have drawn regular polygons and divided those into equal parts.
It's like this : [image]

but I want to fill it with 2 colors like this :

[image]

How do I implement this?
Code how to draw polygons is below:

```
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    nPoints = CalculateVertices(sides, radius, angle, center);

    g.DrawPolygon(navypen, nPoints);
    g.FillPolygon(BlueBrush, nPoints);
    Point center = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
         g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Navy), center.X, center.Y, nPoints[i].X, nPoints[i].Y);

    }

    private PointF[] CalculateVertices(int sides, int radius, float startingAngle, Point center)
    {
        if (sides < 3) {
            sides = 3;
        }
            //throw new ArgumentException("Polygon must have 3 sides or more.");

        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        float step = 360.0f / sides;

        float angle = startingAngle; //starting angle
        for (double i = startingAngle; i < startingAngle + 360.0; i += step) //go in a circle
        {
            points.Add(DegreesToXY(angle, radius, center));
            angle += step;
        }

        return points.ToArray();
    }

    private PointF DegreesToXY(float degrees, float radius, Point origin)
    {
        PointF xy = new PointF();
        double radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;

        xy.X = (int)(Math.Cos(radians) * radius + origin.X);
        xy.Y = (int)(Math.Sin(-radians) * radius + origin.Y);

        return xy;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: `ClientSize/2.Width.X, ClientSize/2.Height.Y` - Basically you need two polygone if you want two colors. -  Also: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - lso: Try to avoid arrays for List<T>. Much nicer to work with!!

Comment: @TaW Oh I typed it wrong and I'm using Winforms(Edited my question!!). I made Color Arrays for two colors but I don't know how to use it..

Comment: You can use [ExtFloodFill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162709(v=vs.85).aspx) function via [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.extfloodfill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways but the most straight-forward is to draw the polygons (triangles) of different colors separately.

Assumig a `List<T>` for colors:

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color> { Color.Yellow, Color.Red };
```

You can add this before the `DrawLine` call:

```
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[i%2]))
    g.FillPolygon(brush, new[] { center, nPoints[i], nPoints[(i+1)% sides]});
```

Note how I wrap around both the `nPoints` and the `colors` using the `%` operator!

[image]

Comment: This idea is brilliant! Thanks a lot